# How to increase Users in developer org with Customer Portal User Licenses

Tags: community, customer-portal

In developer org I am able to create only 5 users with  “Customer Portal User Licenses”. Can we
increase the number of users with this licenses. If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

Developer Orgs come with a limited number of licences purposely and can't be increased without paying for a "more premium" organisation. [This link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Edition) will show you the capabilities of a Developer Org but with regard to licences, you have the following limitations:

> - Salesforce Customer Portal
> - 2 Salesforce CRM licenses
> - 2 Salesforce Mobile licenses
> - 3 Salesforce Platform licenses
> - 5 Salesforce Partner licenses
> - 10 Salesforce Customer Portal Manager licenses

Developer Orgs are literally for just that, development in a limited environment, for students for example or those wanting to flex their muscles in Apex, Visualforce, "401 style" development.

I'd expect the only way to do this might be to contact Salesforce itself but I'd be amazed if they granted any more licences of any kind without some kind of monitary compensation.